# Two polynomials $f$ and $g$ in $k[x,y]$, $k$ algebraically closed, have the same roots iff they have (up to units) the same factors.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to prove this:

> Let $f, g \in \textbf{k}[X,Y]$, where $\textbf{k}$ is an algebraically closed
>   field. Then the equations $f(X,Y)=0$ and $g(X,Y)=0$ have the same
>   solutions if and only if $f$ and $g$ have (up to units) the same
>   irreducible factors.

It is difficult? How can I deal with two variables when algebraically closed tells about polynomials in one variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z(f)$ be the zeros of $f$ and $Z(g)$ is defined similarly. Defined $I(X)$ be the ideals of polynomials vanishing on $X$. Then you have $IZ(f)=\sqrt{(f)}$ by Hilbert Nullstellensatz. Hence you have $\sqrt{(f)}=\sqrt{(g)}$. Now you can write $g^n=af$ and $f^m=bg$ for some $a,b\in k[x,y]$ and $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$. You can see that the irreducible factors of $g$ are also of $f$ and vice versa.

Conversely, it is clear that $f$ and $g$ have the same zeros if they have the same irreducible factors.

Comment: I was thinking about the Gauss Lemma to solve the problem. Any solutions or hints in this way?

Comment: Which Gauss lemma? Are you refering to the lemma that the product of two primitive polynomials is primitive?

Comment: I was thinking about this: Let $R$ be a GCD domain and $F$ its field of fractions. A non-constant polynomial in $R[X]$ is irreducible in $R[X]$ if and only if it is both irreducible in $F[X]$ and primitive in $R[X]$.

Comment: Did you mean you want to see $f(x,y)$ as a polynomial about $y$ with coefficients in $k[x]$?If so, the key point is to show that the solutions(as equations about $x,y$) are the same leads to the same roots in the algebraic closure of $k(x)$.I don't know how to prove it now.Maybe you still need the Nullstellensatz.Maybe you have to use some more complicated knowledge, such as Theorem of Implicit Functions.