# polynomials with same zero set

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Can one find two polynomials $P,Q \in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ with the same non-empty zero set, that have no common factors ?

If we took complex coefficients instead of real coefficients, the answer would be no (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001907/two-polynomials-f-and-g-in-kx-y-k-algebraically-closed-have-the-same)).

Note that $P=X^2+1$ and $Q=Y^2+1$ have no common factors, and the same zero set $\emptyset$. I'm looking for a less trivial example.

EDIT: Is it possible to find an example where the zero set is an infinite set ?

Comment: Do you want a pair with a non-empty zero set? You can take $P(X,Y)=X^2+Y^2$ and $Q(X,Y)=X^4+Y^4$. They both have as zero set $\{(0,0)\}$ but have no common factors in $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for :) if you want to post a quick answer i'll accept it

Comment: It is enough for me that you got you question answered. You can follow up your question, with Can you do the same for larger zero sets? Arbitrary finitely many point? Infinitely many?

Comment: $P,P^2$, and $P^2 + Q^2$ have the same zero sets. With adequate $Q$, the last two polynomials are coprime. That should cover further questions.

Comment: $P^2$ has the same zero set as $P^2+Q^2$ when the zero set of $Q$ contains that of $P$. But at the same time, to prevent them from havign common factors you would need $P,Q$ to not have common factors.

Comment: You're right I got confused. If you want finitely many points, maybe $\sum (X-a)^2(Y-b)^2$ and $\sum (X-a)^2(Y-b)^2 + \prod(X+Y-a-b)^2$ works ?

Comment: But if you want a circle it seems trickier...

Comment: @deyore: Even if you're not motivated by imaginary internet points, please nevertheless write answers as answers rather than comments for the site's sake. A question that was answered in a comment will still appear as "has no answers" in the question lists, making it harder for other users to find places where someone still need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ and $P_{a,b} = a A^2 + bB^2$. Then the family of polynomials $\{P_{a,b} \mid  a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+\}\,$ all have the same zero set $\{(x,y) \mid A(x,y) = 0\} \cap \{(x,y) \mid B(x,y) = 0\} $.

---

[ *EDIT* ] To cover the coprimality question asked in a comment, take for example $A,B$ to have no common factors, then $P_{a,b}$ and $P_{a,2b}$ have no common factors, either.

Comment: It is unclear that any two elements of this family share no common factors.

Comment: @vadim123 Fair point, thanks. Edited the answer to cover that.

Comment: good answer, do you think you can use it to get an infinite zero set ?

Comment: @Sergio I believe the answer is negative, and follows from [Bezout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem#Rigorous_statement).

Comment: indeed, thanks again !